# How to escape brackets in mu4e search queries?

Tags: search, mu4e, escape

Title says it all.

I want to have a search query which matches all messages whose *Subject* starts with `[Spam]`.  So far, I tried the following:

- `[Spam]`
- `[spam]`
- `\[Spam\]`
- `\[Spam\]`
- `\\[Spam\\]`
- `\\[Spam\\]`

I'd appreciate any pointer in the right direction ...

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot search for special characters like `[` in mu/mu4e/Xapian (the underlying database mu-find queries). The best I know of is to use the `subject` (`s`) flag, with a query that starts like so:`s:spam` (mu searches are always case-insensitive).

This is, admittedly, a little less precise than you might like, but is a side-effect of mu's "be as eager as possible in matching" approach, I believe.